# No cordova.local.properties file created by using cmd sencha cordova init com.mycompany.MyApp MyApp

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I am executing this cmd

```
sencha cordova init com.mycompany.MyApp MyApp
```

cordova folder created but cordova.local.properties not appear

This is my app.json

```
"builds": {
        "web": {"default": true},
        "native": {
            "packager": "cordova",
            "cordova" : {
                "config": {
                   // Uncomment the line below and add the platforms you wish to build for
                    //“platforms": "ios android wp8 blackberry”,

                    "id": "com.domain.HELLO123",
                    "name": "HELLO123"
                }
            }
        }
```

Please tell me what step i am missing.I want to build remote build